# posgresql puts parentheses around each query result when defining a function

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to write this function which will do a query on multiple schemas matching the pattern `myschema_%`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION all_things_counts_dynamic() RETURNS TABLE (col1 int) AS $$
DECLARE
    schema RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR schema IN EXECUTE
        format('SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name like %L', 'myschema_%')
        LOOP
            RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
                format('select count(*) from %s.things', schema);
        END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I execute it, I get this error

```
select all_things_counts_dynamic();
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...nt(*) from (myschema_07a3).things...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  select count(*) from (myschema_07a3).things
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function all_things_counts_dynamic() line 8 at RETURN QUERY
```

It looks like it is wrapping the results of the schema query in parentheses.  How do I fix this?

I also tried `%I` instead of `%s`.

Comment: If you want to have `schema` as a `RECORD`(not a good choice for a name by the way) you will need to do: `...things', schema.schema_name` to unpack the name out of the `RECORD`. Otherwise have `schema` be `varchar` so you can use it directly.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - thank you.  `schema.schema_name` worked!   I also tried changing `RECORD` to `varchar` but that lead to a sql structure error

Answer (score 1):

A variable of type `record` is a composite type, whose string representation is in parentheses.

Since you select only a single column from `information_schema.schemata`, you could define the variable like this:

```
DECLARE
   p_schema text;
```

I use the name `p_schema` to avoid confusion with the unreserved keyword `schema`.

The second `format` call is also vulnerable to SQL injection and would cause an error if a schema name is a quoted identifier. Use the `%I` placeholder:

```
format('select count(*) from %I.things', p_schema);
```